# grid view does not getting update the on screen view

Tags: android

My android app is about displaying image.There might be thousands of images.So loading that much images at once can crash the app.So i am loading first 100 images at once, then after finishing first 100 images it will call web service and again loading next 100 images.I am shuffling the array each time when response comes from server.But after shuffling, on screen images are not  updating.It means when I click on single image to open then opening different image than we see on grid view single row.I got the problem as I am shuffling whole array after getting response from server.But how to manage this issue?Please help me.Thank u in advance.
This is my Tablet_Photos.java

```
/************************************ Call webservice For loading all Photos ***********************************************************************/

private void CallWebservice(String cid, String scid,int ShuffleFlag) {
    newarray.clear();


    /*Log.e("cid","--->"+cid);
    Log.e("scid","--->"+scid);*/
    arrayList.clear();
    String url = Constant.getphotoscid;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences3 = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    username = sharedPreferences3.getString("username", null);
    String timessstamp = sharedPreferences3.getString("timess", null);
    Log.e("app", ".,....subsciption end date is....username..." + username);
    arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", ""));
    arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", username));
    arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid", cid));
    // arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scid",scid));
    arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scid", scid));
    arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timestamp", timessstamp));
    arrayList
            .add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", String.valueOf(pagecount)));
    //Log.e("fav", "....url" + url + "...arraylist" + arrayList.toString());

    new WebConnectionAsync(url, arrayList, Tablet_Photos.this,ShuffleFlag).execute();

}

public class WebConnectionAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Object> {

    String val = null;
    int ShuffleFlag=0;
    ProgressDialog pd = null;
    Context context = null;
    List<NameValuePair> argList = null;
    String url = null;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public WebConnectionAsync(String url, List<NameValuePair> argList,
            Context ctx,int ShuffleFlag) {
        this.url = url;
        this.ShuffleFlag=ShuffleFlag;
        this.argList = argList;
        context = ctx;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        photos_pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Tablet_Photos.this, "",
                "Please Wait...");
        if(ShuffleFlag==1)
        {

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            val = HttpConnection.postData(url, argList);
            val = val.toString();
            GetPhotos(val);
            Log.e("response", "we" + val);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Problem with server. Please try again later.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return val;
    }

    private void GetPhotos(String val2) {
        //ArrayList<DataSet> tempArray=new ArrayList<DataSet>();
        try {

            ArrayList<DataSet> new_array = new ArrayList<DataSet>();
            ArrayList<DataSet> mostdownload_array = new ArrayList<DataSet>();
            ArrayList<DataSet> featured_array = new ArrayList<DataSet>();
            ArrayList<DataSet> old_array = new ArrayList<DataSet>();

            //array.clear();
            //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(val2);
            JSONObject messageActivityResult = jsonObj
                    .getJSONObject("PhotoResult");
            if (messageActivityResult.getString("status").equals("Ok")) {

                totalpagecount = messageActivityResult
                        .getString("totalPages");

                // *******************Saving timestamp into shared
                // Perfernces*********************************
                String tstimestamp = messageActivityResult
                        .getString("currentTStamp");
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("timess", tstimestamp);
                editor.commit();
                Log.e("scroll", "...total page count is..."
                        + totalpagecount);
                if (pagecount <= Integer.parseInt(totalpagecount)) {
                    pagecount++;
                    Log.e("scroll", "...page count if conditon");

                }
                if (GlobalVariables.isSuscribed.equals("0")) {
                    // ****************************** array for new Images
                    // *****************************************************************
                    JSONArray message = messageActivityResult
                            .getJSONArray("JSImages");
                    Log.e("yg", ".....message activity res..new,...."
                            + messageActivityResult
                                    .getJSONArray("JSImages").length());

                    Log.e("yg", ".....message activity ,...."
                            + messageActivityResult.toString());

                    // ******************** NEW PHOTOS
                    // ARRAY***********************************************
                    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                        DataSet d = new DataSet();
                        JSONObject jsoObj = message.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject messageobject = jsoObj
                                .getJSONObject("JSImage");

                        if (messageobject.getString("photoSortType")
                                .equals("new")) {
                            d.setPid((messageobject.getString("pid")));
                            d.setPname((messageobject.getString("pname")));
                            d.setSort(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoSortType"));
                            d.setTags(messageobject.getString("tags"));
                            d.setPhotoname(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoname"));

                            d.setPhotodeatils((messageobject
                                    .getString("photodetails")));
                            d.setPhotoresoultion((messageobject
                                    .getString("photoresolution")));
                            d.setIshighresoltion((messageobject
                                    .getString("ishighResol")));
                            d.setHighurl((messageobject
                                    .getString("highurl")));
                            d.setUrl((messageobject.getString("thumbUrl")));
                            d.setIsfav((messageobject
                                    .getString("isFavorite")));
                            d.setPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("photograpgher")));

                            d.setWidth(350);
                            d.setHeight(350);
                            d.setIsPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("isPhotographer")));
                            new_array.add(d);
                        }

                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<new_array.size();i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=i+1;j<new_array.size();j++)
                        {
                            if(new_array.get(i).getPid().equals(new_array.get(j).getPid()))
                            {
                                new_array.remove(j);
                                j--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    /*long seed = System.nanoTime();

                    Collections.shuffle(new_array, new Random(seed));*/

                    Log.e("array", "new array..." + new_array.size());
                    // ******************** MOST DOWNLOADED PHOTOS
                    // ARRAY***********************************************
                    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                        DataSet d = new DataSet();
                        JSONObject jsoObj = message.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject messageobject = jsoObj
                                .getJSONObject("JSImage");

                        if (messageobject.getString("photoSortType")
                                .equals("mostDownloaded")) {
                            d.setPid((messageobject.getString("pid")));
                            d.setPname((messageobject.getString("pname")));
                            d.setSort(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoSortType"));
                            d.setTags(messageobject.getString("tags"));
                            d.setPhotoname(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoname"));

                            d.setPhotodeatils((messageobject
                                    .getString("photodetails")));
                            d.setPhotoresoultion((messageobject
                                    .getString("photoresolution")));
                            d.setIshighresoltion((messageobject
                                    .getString("ishighResol")));
                            d.setHighurl((messageobject
                                    .getString("highurl")));
                            d.setUrl((messageobject.getString("thumbUrl")));
                            d.setIsfav((messageobject
                                    .getString("isFavorite")));
                            d.setPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("photograpgher")));

                            d.setWidth(350);
                            d.setHeight(350);
                            d.setIsPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("isPhotographer")));
                            mostdownload_array.add(d);
                        }

                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<mostdownload_array.size();i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=i+1;j<mostdownload_array.size();j++)
                        {
                            if(mostdownload_array.get(i).getPid().equals(mostdownload_array.get(j).getPid()))
                            {
                                mostdownload_array.remove(j);
                                j--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    /*seed = System.nanoTime();

                    Collections.shuffle(mostdownload_array,
                            new Random(seed));*/

                    Log.e("array", "mostDownloaded array..."
                            + mostdownload_array.size());

                    // ******************** FEATUIRED PHOTOS
                    // ARRAY***********************************************
                    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                        DataSet d = new DataSet();
                        JSONObject jsoObj = message.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject messageobject = jsoObj
                                .getJSONObject("JSImage");

                        if (messageobject.getString("photoSortType")
                                .equals("featured")) {
                            d.setPid((messageobject.getString("pid")));
                            d.setPname((messageobject.getString("pname")));
                            d.setSort(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoSortType"));
                            d.setTags(messageobject.getString("tags"));
                            d.setPhotoname(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoname"));

                            d.setPhotodeatils((messageobject
                                    .getString("photodetails")));
                            d.setPhotoresoultion((messageobject
                                    .getString("photoresolution")));
                            d.setIshighresoltion((messageobject
                                    .getString("ishighResol")));
                            d.setHighurl((messageobject
                                    .getString("highurl")));
                            d.setUrl((messageobject.getString("thumbUrl")));
                            d.setIsfav((messageobject
                                    .getString("isFavorite")));
                            d.setPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("photograpgher")));

                            d.setWidth(350);
                            d.setHeight(350);
                            d.setIsPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("isPhotographer")));
                            featured_array.add(d);
                        }

                    }

                    for(int i=0;i<featured_array.size();i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=i+1;j<featured_array.size();j++)
                        {
                            if(featured_array.get(i).getPid().equals(featured_array.get(j).getPid()))
                            {
                                featured_array.remove(j);
                                j--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    /*seed = System.nanoTime();

                    Collections.shuffle(featured_array, new Random(seed));*/

                    Log.e("array",
                            "featured array..." + featured_array.size());

                    // ******************** OLD PHOTOS
                    // ARRAY***********************************************
                    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                        DataSet d = new DataSet();
                        JSONObject jsoObj = message.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject messageobject = jsoObj
                                .getJSONObject("JSImage");

                        if (messageobject.getString("photoSortType")
                                .equals("old")) {
                            d.setPid((messageobject.getString("pid")));
                            d.setPname((messageobject.getString("pname")));
                            d.setSort(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoSortType"));
                            d.setTags(messageobject.getString("tags"));
                            d.setPhotoname(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoname"));

                            d.setPhotodeatils((messageobject
                                    .getString("photodetails")));
                            d.setPhotoresoultion((messageobject
                                    .getString("photoresolution")));
                            d.setIshighresoltion((messageobject
                                    .getString("ishighResol")));
                            d.setHighurl((messageobject
                                    .getString("highurl")));
                            d.setUrl((messageobject.getString("thumbUrl")));
                            d.setIsfav((messageobject
                                    .getString("isFavorite")));
                            d.setPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("photograpgher")));

                            d.setWidth(350);
                            d.setHeight(350);
                            d.setIsPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("isPhotographer")));
                            old_array.add(d);
                        }

                    }

                    for(int i=0;i<old_array.size();i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=i+1;j<old_array.size();j++)
                        {
                            if(old_array.get(i).getPid().equals(old_array.get(j).getPid()))
                            {
                                old_array.remove(j);
                                j--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    /*seed = System.nanoTime();

                    Collections.shuffle(old_array, new Random(seed));*/

                    Log.e("array", "old array..." + old_array.size());
                    array.addAll(new_array);
                    array.addAll(featured_array);
                    array.addAll(mostdownload_array);
                    array.addAll(old_array);
                    /*tempArray.addAll(new_array);
                    tempArray.addAll(featured_array);
                    tempArray.addAll(mostdownload_array);
                    tempArray.addAll(old_array);*/


                    Log.e("array",
                            "..for UNSubscribed user...data in array..."
                                    + array.toString());


                }
                // *****************************for Subscribe
                // user*********************************************
                else if (GlobalVariables.isSuscribed.equals("1")) {

                    ArrayList<DataSet> new_array1 = new ArrayList<DataSet>();
                    ArrayList<DataSet> mostdownload_array1 = new ArrayList<DataSet>();
                    ArrayList<DataSet> featured_array1 = new ArrayList<DataSet>();
                    ArrayList<DataSet> old_array1 = new ArrayList<DataSet>();
                    // ****************************** array for new Images
                    // *****************************************************************
                    JSONArray message = messageActivityResult
                            .getJSONArray("JSImages");
                    Log.e("yg", ".....message activity res..new,...."
                            + messageActivityResult
                                    .getJSONArray("JSImages").length());

                    Log.e("yg", ".....message activity ,...."
                            + messageActivityResult.toString());

                    // ******************** NEW PHOTOS
                    // ARRAY***********************************************
                    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                        DataSet d = new DataSet();
                        JSONObject jsoObj = message.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject messageobject = jsoObj
                                .getJSONObject("JSImage");

                        if (messageobject.getString("photoSortType")
                                .equals("new")) {
                            d.setPid((messageobject.getString("pid")));
                            d.setPname((messageobject.getString("pname")));
                            d.setSort(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoSortType"));
                            d.setTags(messageobject.getString("tags"));
                            d.setPhotoname(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoname"));

                            d.setPhotodeatils((messageobject
                                    .getString("photodetails")));
                            d.setPhotoresoultion((messageobject
                                    .getString("photoresolution")));
                            d.setIshighresoltion((messageobject
                                    .getString("ishighResol")));
                            d.setHighurl((messageobject
                                    .getString("highurl")));
                            d.setUrl((messageobject.getString("thumbUrl")));
                            d.setIsfav((messageobject
                                    .getString("isFavorite")));
                            d.setPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("photograpgher")));

                            d.setWidth(350);
                            d.setHeight(350);
                            d.setIsPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("isPhotographer")));
                            new_array1.add(d);
                        }

                    }
                    /*long seed = System.nanoTime();

                    Collections.shuffle(new_array1, new Random(seed));*/
                    for(int i=0;i<new_array1.size();i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=i+1;j<new_array1.size();j++)
                        {
                            if(new_array1.get(i).getPid().equals(new_array1.get(j).getPid()))
                            {
                                new_array1.remove(j);
                                j--;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Log.e("array", "new array..." + new_array1.size());
                    // ******************** MOST DOWNLOADED PHOTOS
                    // ARRAY***********************************************
                    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                        DataSet d = new DataSet();
                        JSONObject jsoObj = message.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject messageobject = jsoObj
                                .getJSONObject("JSImage");

                        if (messageobject.getString("photoSortType")
                                .equals("mostDownloaded")) {
                            d.setPid((messageobject.getString("pid")));
                            d.setPname((messageobject.getString("pname")));
                            d.setSort(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoSortType"));
                            d.setTags(messageobject.getString("tags"));
                            d.setPhotoname(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoname"));

                            d.setPhotodeatils((messageobject
                                    .getString("photodetails")));
                            d.setPhotoresoultion((messageobject
                                    .getString("photoresolution")));
                            d.setIshighresoltion((messageobject
                                    .getString("ishighResol")));
                            d.setHighurl((messageobject
                                    .getString("highurl")));
                            d.setUrl((messageobject.getString("thumbUrl")));
                            d.setIsfav((messageobject
                                    .getString("isFavorite")));
                            d.setPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("photograpgher")));

                            d.setWidth(350);
                            d.setHeight(350);
                            d.setIsPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("isPhotographer")));
                            mostdownload_array1.add(d);
                        }

                    }
                    /*seed = System.nanoTime();

                    Collections.shuffle(mostdownload_array1, new Random(
                            seed));*/
                    for(int i=0;i<mostdownload_array1.size();i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=i+1;j<mostdownload_array1.size();j++)
                        {
                            if(mostdownload_array1.get(i).getPid().equals(mostdownload_array1.get(j).getPid()))
                            {
                                mostdownload_array1.remove(j);
                                j--;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Log.e("array", "mostDownloaded array..."
                            + mostdownload_array1.size());

                    // ******************** FEATUIRED PHOTOS
                    // ARRAY***********************************************
                    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                        DataSet d = new DataSet();
                        JSONObject jsoObj = message.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject messageobject = jsoObj
                                .getJSONObject("JSImage");

                        if (messageobject.getString("photoSortType")
                                .equals("featured")) {
                            d.setPid((messageobject.getString("pid")));
                            d.setPname((messageobject.getString("pname")));
                            d.setSort(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoSortType"));
                            d.setTags(messageobject.getString("tags"));
                            d.setPhotoname(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoname"));

                            d.setPhotodeatils((messageobject
                                    .getString("photodetails")));
                            d.setPhotoresoultion((messageobject
                                    .getString("photoresolution")));
                            d.setIshighresoltion((messageobject
                                    .getString("ishighResol")));
                            d.setHighurl((messageobject
                                    .getString("highurl")));
                            d.setUrl((messageobject.getString("thumbUrl")));
                            d.setIsfav((messageobject
                                    .getString("isFavorite")));
                            d.setPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("photograpgher")));

                            d.setWidth(350);
                            d.setHeight(350);
                            d.setIsPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("isPhotographer")));
                            featured_array1.add(d);
                        }

                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<featured_array1.size();i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=i+1;j<featured_array1.size();j++)
                        {
                            if(featured_array1.get(i).getPid().equals(featured_array1.get(j).getPid()))
                            {
                                featured_array1.remove(j);
                                j--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("array",
                            "featured array..." + featured_array1.size());

                    // ******************** OLD PHOTOS
                    // ARRAY***********************************************
                    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                        DataSet d = new DataSet();
                        JSONObject jsoObj = message.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject messageobject = jsoObj
                                .getJSONObject("JSImage");

                        if (messageobject.getString("photoSortType")
                                .equals("old")) {
                            d.setPid((messageobject.getString("pid")));
                            d.setPname((messageobject.getString("pname")));
                            d.setSort(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoSortType"));
                            d.setTags(messageobject.getString("tags"));
                            d.setPhotoname(messageobject
                                    .getString("photoname"));

                            d.setPhotodeatils((messageobject
                                    .getString("photodetails")));
                            d.setPhotoresoultion((messageobject
                                    .getString("photoresolution")));
                            d.setIshighresoltion((messageobject
                                    .getString("ishighResol")));
                            d.setHighurl((messageobject
                                    .getString("highurl")));
                            d.setUrl((messageobject.getString("thumbUrl")));
                            d.setIsfav((messageobject
                                    .getString("isFavorite")));
                            d.setPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("photograpgher")));

                            d.setWidth(350);
                            d.setHeight(350);
                            d.setIsPhotographer((messageobject
                                    .getString("isPhotographer")));
                            old_array1.add(d);
                        }

                    }
                    //featured_array1.addAll(old_array1);
                    /*seed = System.nanoTime();

                    Collections.shuffle(old_array1, new Random(seed));*/
                    for(int i=0;i<old_array1.size();i++)
                    {
                        for(int j=i+1;j<old_array1.size();j++)
                        {
                            if(old_array1.get(i).getPid().equals(old_array1.get(j).getPid()))
                            {
                                old_array1.remove(j);
                                j--;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Log.e("array", "old array..." + old_array1.size());
                    array.addAll(new_array1);
                    array.addAll(featured_array1);
                    array.addAll(mostdownload_array1);
                    array.addAll(old_array1);
                    /*tempArray.addAll(new_array1);
                    tempArray.addAll(featured_array1);
                    tempArray.addAll(mostdownload_array1);
                    tempArray.addAll(old_array1);*/
                    Log.e("array",
                            "...for Subscribed user.data in array..."
                                    + array.toString());

                }



                //Collections.shuffle(array,new Random(System.nanoTime()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Collections.shuffle(tempArray,new Random(System.nanoTime()));

        for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<array.size();j++)
            {
                if(array.get(i).getPid().equals(array.get(j).getPid()))
                {
                    array.remove(j);
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
        //array.addAll(tempArray);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("ShuffleFlag","--->"+String.valueOf(ShuffleFlag));

        if(ShuffleFlag==1)
        {   
            Collections.shuffle(array);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        photos_pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < array.size(); ii++) {
            newarray.add(array.get(ii));
        }
        Log.e("new array", "..new array..." + newarray + "........");
        /*
         * mAdapter = new STGVAdapter(Tablet_Photos.this,
         * getApplication(),array);
         * 
         * ptrstgv.setAdapter(mAdapter); mAdapter.getMoreItem();
         */
        if (count1 == 0) {
            mAdapter = new STGVAdapter(Tablet_Photos.this,
                    getApplication(), array);
            ptrstgv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            count1++;
        }
        /*else
        {
            mAdapter11=new STGVAdapter(Tablet_Photos.this, getApplication(),array);
            ptrstgv.setAdapter(mAdapter11);
        }*/

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        try {
            dialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exce", "" + e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: your problem is that you are shuffeling the images. you obviously need a key to know which thumbnail belongs to which image, you cant refer to it, by its position.

Comment: Sorry,I am beginner.So can u elaborate your solution.